# Old patents worth any value

Tags: filing

http://patent.ipexl.com/inventor/scott_ernest_george_1.html

I hold several original patents in their original leather covers belonging to earnest George Scott. This one is the patent for  The improvements in the manufacture of acetic acid dated 1897. No 12952.
I was just hoping someone could help by telling me keep them or throw them. Or might a museum be interested. Thank you

Comment: While historic documents may have a collectible value, unfortunately it is not on topic on this site - which is about the patent process and currently active patents.

Answer (score 1):

A museum might be interested but I'm not sure if they have much/any value. I'm sure they're worth a few dollars. If you're just going to throw them away, I'd be interested in them. I'm brand new here so I don't know if you can PM me, but if you can . . .